# android webview show credentials popup

Tags: android, webview

Here is the link where I want to login:

http://audidome-dev.webspaces.vektorrausch.net/app/login.php

and in normal browser it looks so

[image: shoul be so]

but I can't get this popup in my WebView.

Here is my code:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://audidome-dev.webspaces.vektorrausch.net/app/login.php");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebView won't display this pop-up. It will [ask you for the credentials](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and it's up to you to fill the credentials (display the pop-up).